# Denying facebook authentication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made an application which allows a user to login using their facebook account.  Everything works find if they click "allow" when asked if they want give my application permission to access certain details from their facebook account.  However, when they click "deny", it just keeps looping and keeps asking them if they want to give permission to the application.  How do I get it to go to another page when they click "deny" instead of it continously looping and asking the same question?

I've tried looking at the documentation, but can't seem to find what I'm after.

Before asking for permission, the following is executed, then if I click "don't allow", it just keeps looping through the code below until I click "allow":

```
<?php

session_start();

require("facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'app id goes here',
    'secret' => 'secret goes here',
    'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {

    try{

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');

        $_SESSION['returned'] = array("id" => $uid, "name" => $user["name"], "access_token" => $session['access_token']);

        header('Location: returned.php');
        exit;

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "something is wrong";
        exit;

    }

} else {

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);

}
```

Comment: Check @uncreative 's solution, it should help. incase it doesn't work, please put up some of your code here, specifically the script that is handling the facebook authentication, so that we can help you debug :)

Comment: @DroidUser, please see updated question, it includes the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) it will redirect the user to the page you provided: http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

In the page you redirect to check for url parameter "error"
In addition on success there should be a url parameter "code" which you should verify exists before proceeding

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
  header('Location: URL_TO_GO_IF_FAILED');
} else {
  // ... whatever you were doing before
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding your suggesting to my existing code above just before the 'else' but changed your `if` to an `elseif` and it never seems to get to it when I click "don't allow".

Comment: Got it working, I had to add the url in the facebook.php file.